# Asp.Net KeyValuePair<string, { } > does not contain definition or extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've created a web app where you can leave recommendations for a person, a person can have multiple recommendations, and got to the point where I'd like to view all recommendations for a particular Person. Once I click on the link to view the recommendations I get an error saying :

> 'KeyValuePair <`string, Recommendation> does not contain a definition for 'Recommendations' and no extension method 'Recommendations' accepting a first argument of type 'KeyValuePair' could be found.

Here's some of my code, hopefully someone can help me resolve this issue I've been stuck on for hours.

**Recommendation Controller**

```html
using Lab3Models.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Lab3Models.Controllers
{
    public class RecommendationController : Controller
    {
        private static IDictionary<string, Person> _people = null;
        
        ....

        public ActionResult Show(string id)
        {
            if (Session["people"] != null)
            {
                _people = (Dictionary<string, Person>)Session["people"];
            }
            else
            {
              _people = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
                Session["people"] = _people;
            }
            if (!_people.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                return HttpNotFound("Sorry, but can't find id: " + id);
            }
            return View(_people[id]);    
        }
    }
}
```

**Person & Recommendation Models**

```html
public class Person
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Recommendation> Recommendations { get; set; }

        public Person()
        {
            Recommendations = new List<Recommendation>();
        }
    }


public class Recommendation
    { 
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public string Narrative { get; set; }
        public string RecommenderName { get; set; }
        public Person ThePerson { get; set; }
    }
```

**Show View**

```html
@model IDictionary<string, Lab3Models.Models.Recommendation>

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Id
        </th>
        <th>
            Rating
        </th>
        <th>
            Narrative
        </th>
        <th>
            Recommender's Name
        </th>
    </tr>
             
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        foreach (var rec in item.Recommendations)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Value.Id
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Value.Rating
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Value.Narrative
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Value.RecommenderName
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

Please, any help would be great.

**EDIT**
Iterating over a dictionary isn't my problem though, I've iterated through my person dictionary already to display all people I've added to the list. My problem is showing the list of recommendations for a particular person from the original person dictionary.

Comment: Your model in the view is `IDictionary<string, Lab3Models.Models.Recommendation>` and your using a nested `foreach` loop to attempt to iterate over it which is not correct (it is a problem and you need to refer the dupe to understand how to iterate over a dictionary). But your view makes no sense and has no relationship to the controller code you have show which returns `Person` to a view (not a `Dictionary`) and then it would be `foreach(var rec in Model.Recommendations) { ... }`

Comment: So, essentially my Show method in the controller is wrong because theres no relationship to recommendation?

Comment: `return View(_people[id]);` returns a `Person` which contains property a collection of `Recommendation`, so your view would need to be `@model Person` (but you cannot have shown the correct code since this would throw a different exception)